# May i know about how to print sysLog level alert into a file in java

Tags: alert, syslog

The standard Java logging defines the following log levels:

```
WARNING
INFO
CONFIG
ERROR
```

This is incompatible to RFC 5424, because it lacks a ALERT level. Java lacks some additional log levels (critical and emergency).

Is there any way to extend the list of possible log levels in order to add the missing ALERT level? Or is it necessary to rewrite the whole logging?

Comment: You are missing a *lot* of required info here: 1. you seem to be using commons logging? 2. what implementation are you using with commons logging? 3. syslog defines 8 severity levels whereas commons logging defines 6 levels, so you cannot expect a 1:1 match between the two. 4. as you can see in the relevant Javadoc, the Log interface does not define an "alert" method.  So, tell us what you want to achieve, and how your setup is configured and we will be able to help you better. In its present form, the question is unanswerable.

Comment: Log interface does not define an "alert" method yes, but where it is defined ?
my requirement to print a alert level. which method i need to use or which interface i need use @fvu

Comment: You just answered your own question. It's nowhere defined, because it doesn't have an "alert" method. But if my assumption of what you're looking for is correct, you'll find it in the [apache logging documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/guide.html) under **"Logging a Message"**

Comment: As @fvu said, when you ask a question (on any forum), provide some more information on what you're using in your setup and what you're trying to achieve. The more information somebody else has, the easier it is to replicate the error and to help.

Comment: i need to print syslog alert level in log file by using java. @eDonkey

Comment: If the documentation didn't help you, please provide more information on what your setup looks like (e.g. config files) and what you've tried to solve your problem. We can't help you, if you don't provide more information.

Comment: Just repeating what you already tried and that obviously did not work won't get us anywhere. @eDonkey already gave you a good tip, now it's up to you to improve the question, otherwise it risks getting closed as lacking information.